# Intellisense Not Detecting Variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I am having a weird issue and for the last couple of hours I've been searching and trying all kinds of fixes and nothing worked.

The thing is when I create a project the Intellisense stops recognizing the local variables in all the new classes I add. For example if I declare "bool success;" in Program.cs and then start typing "success" everything works as usual...

BUT when I add a new class and in it I declare "bool success;" when I start typing "success" Intellisense just doesn't find the variable like it doesn't exist.

What I've already tried:

1. Deleting the .suo file
2. Resetting VS settings
3. running "devenv /resetskippkgs"
4. Pressing ctrl + alt + space

It happened this morning and I have no idea how.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your code actually valid? Intellisense will have a harder time on code which doesn't build. Are you able to build with no problems? Can you post an example "new class"?

Comment: As somebody posted here (and later deleted their post) - it is working inside a declared method. Thanks, whoever that was!

Comment: protection level ???, maybe you're declaring class XXXX{...

Comment: Hey that was me.. I was not sure. So, deleted it :) (thought that may look as insulting)

Comment: Sometimes the Intellisense database gets broken. Try deleting the file (.ncb).

Answer (score 0):

The Intellisense for created variables will work in declared methods not in the class. because in a class you cant assign values to a variable but you can assign values to the variables in a method.

```
In a class, variables can be declared but cant assign values to them
In a method, variables can be declared and also values can be assigned to them.
```

So, the Intellisense doesnt show up the variable name in a class after it has been declared as there is no use to show it.

and also if the `Class` property has *Build Action* set to *Content* state then the intellisense will not work. To correct it, just set *Build Action* to *Compile* state.